# Graph change - in order to have only one minimum spanning tree

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am a computer science student, during my studies I was exposed to this question:

I am given a graph that has a number of minimal spanning trees. I need to change the edge weights linearly - in order to have only one spanning tree. This tree should be minimal - even in the original graph.

I tried to go over all the edges- and make sure there was no edge - with the same weight.

But this solution did not work properly for me - when there is a graph that is circular - deleting a certain edge - or changing the weight of a certain edge would not give the minimum spanning tree that was at first.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Pick a minimal spanning tree, and increase the weight of all edges not in this tree?

Comment: Thanks for the response, it has helped me tremendously, do I need to increase weight for edges by using croscale?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what croscale is.

Comment: Sorry for the interruption, I meant Kruskal.

Comment: Your question does not mention any bounds as to the number of edge weights you can update. If there is no limit in the number of edges you can update, then as @PaulHankin suggested you can find _a_ minimum spanning tree (with Prim's or Kruskal's algorithms) and then update all the other edges to have the weight `w`, where `w` is greater than the largest weight `v` in your minimum spanning tree.